# Best way to smart update a directory in Windows (i.e. changes only, like rsync for unix)

Tags: windows-xp, sync

I'd like to update the contents of a unc directory with a local directory, but due to network speed issues I'd like to only send the updates to that directory.

Is there any software that can aid me in that task?

Comment: You could use Git or Svn or a similar source control tool. Whether that's the right answer depends on the contents of the directory and your use case.

Answer (score 4):

There *are* **rsync** tools for Windows like [cwRsync](http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html) and  [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) (both wrap rsync, afaik)
You will find some more references at this StackOverflow question: [Rsync for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/528298)

Personally, I'd just setup [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) and use rsync from in there.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to take a look at **Robocopy**.  It's been a part of windows since Vista/Wins2k8.  The /MIR option may be useful and in the resource kit prior to that. Careful to test on TEST data!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Microsoft SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15155) or the built-in [Offline Files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Understanding-offline-files) feature.